coldstart of vercel's serverless function suddenly became very slow
I used and deployed next.js using vercel.
Some pages that normally use getServersideProps took about 2 seconds with a long coldstart.
But yesterday, suddenly it was slowing down to almost 10 seconds.
The issue went away spontaneously after 30 minutes.
Do you have any idea why this happened?
I have exceeded the 1M edge request usage that comes with the hobby plan, could this have anything to do with the issue?
The environment
vercel (hobby plan)
next.js v.12

Have you tried to downgrade next or vercel?

We are experiencing the same issue in preview environments. No clue what causes this. We are on a pro plan though
